# Visual Studio Android Emulator couldn't install

Tags: android-emulator, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I should install VS Android Emulator but I can't. Because VS Android Emulator doesn't show in installer. I use Macbook Pro that installed Windows 10 Education and it support VT. Also I has installed Hyper-V and I can start virtual machine. I has tried for VS 2015 Community and Enterprise but it hasn't emulator. What can I do to install VS Android Emulator and What is system requirements?

**Edit:**
I upgrade Windows to Enterprise edition and Android Emulator is working. I think Windows 10 Education Edition is not fine for Hyper-V.

Comment: There is a bug in Win10 Education that prevents the emulator from working correctly. It should support Hyper-V, but doesn't have the local admins group necessary for that. The Windows team is looking into it!

Comment: I was unable to get the Android Emulator to work on Enterprise.  I tried two fresh installs with Azure AD account option and personal account and neither worked.  I was able to get the emulator to work with Windows 10 Pro.  The issue was the Hyper-V Administrators group was not created on the Enterprise SKU.

Answer (score 1):

The VS Emulator for Android requires Hyper-V, which is only available in certain versions of Windows 10. Windows 10 Home and Education editions do not have Hyper-V, so you'll need Windows 10 Pro or greater to use the emulator.

Comment: it is mentioned in official windows 10 Microsoft web that Windows 10 Education has Hyper V installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the emulator by itself from this link:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/msft-android-emulator-vs.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much. But this solution doesn't work. Emulator installed but it doesn't work. I have "[Critical] Unable to add user to the Hyper-V Administrators group. Exit code 2220." error.

Comment: @YasinUğurYıldız error 2220 = NERR_GroupNotFound ( The group name could not be found.). Make sure there is a Hyper-v user group on your system.

Answer (score 0):

The VS Emulator for Android does not work on Windows 10 (for me).

My advice is do not worry because there are *much* better options. I use Genemotion & VirtualBox with Hyper-V disabled and it is great. Also, the Google Android emulator with HAXM is great.

Google emulators include two versions (with and without Google APIs). And I've been able to successfully install Google Play services in Genemotion on 4.4.4 hosts.

Therefore, either the Google or Genemotion options are *extremely* more useful than Microsoft's VS Emulator for Android on Hyper-V (even if it worked on Windows 10).